# Find beginning of date interval from list intervals for all reference dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following values:

```
A               B               C               D
Reference Date  Start Interval  End Interval    Belong to date interval starting on
5/11/2021       4/28/2021       5/11/2021       4/28/2021
5/19/2021       5/12/2021       5/25/2021       5/12/2021
5/20/2021       5/26/2021       6/8/2021        5/12/2021
5/12/2021       6/9/2021        6/22/2021       5/12/2021
5/5/2021        6/23/2021       7/6/2021        4/28/2021
5/25/2021       7/7/2021        7/20/2021       5/12/2021
5/11/2021       7/21/2021       8/3/2021        4/28/2021
4/30/2021       8/4/2021        8/17/2021       4/28/2021
5/11/2021       8/18/2021       8/31/2021       4/28/2021
5/5/2021        9/1/2021        9/14/2021       4/28/2021
5/18/2021       9/15/2021       9/28/2021       5/12/2021
4/28/2021       9/29/2021       10/12/2021      4/28/2021
4/28/2021       10/13/2021      10/26/2021      4/28/2021
4/28/2021       10/27/2021      11/9/2021       4/28/2021
5/5/2021        11/10/2021      11/23/2021      4/28/2021
5/14/2021       11/24/2021      12/7/2021       5/12/2021
```

The intervals (column `B` and `C`) don't have overlap I would like to have an `arrayformula` in column D2, which finds the start date of the corresponding interval the reference date belongs to. I have blanks after the last filled rows, so I would need to exclude in the calculation the blanks rows.

I was trying to implement the following formula, but I am getting correct only the first two rows:
[image: Using arrayformula, but it doesn't calculate correctly after the second row]

***Note:*** In my case intervals are ordered in ascending order. They were generated as 2-week's duration, starting on Wednesdays and ending on Tuesdays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, B2:B, 1, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: It works!, would you explain how it works? IFNA has a second mandatory input argument, I guess if not present, then an empty value is returned. Using `is_sorted` input argument as 1 (or TRUE), then you get the lower or equal condition. So the formula can be expressed like this too `ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, B2:B, 1, true),))`. How the value is obtained for row 17th for example. The evaluation should be `ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A17, B17:B, 1, true),))`, so the value: `12/05/2021`is not part the range. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal we VLOOKUP column A in column B and returning 1st column = B column by using approximation mode (the last 1) instead of exact mode (which would be 0). this will allow us to find either the exact date which matches A & B, or if the A is higher the vlookup will try to find the lower state. in case of no match or error, IFNA will nullify such errors